# Javascript Table Column Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> Update Explanation:

I have a table and which has 5 columns and I have 6 `step` for each column. So I want to match each column based on these `step`. Inside .`step` have 5 column direction and one confirmation text. `step` code like this :

```
<div class="table_required">
  <div class="column facebook">Select the column that has the <span>Facebook</span> details</div>
  <div class="column twitter">Select the column that has the <span>Twitter</span> details</div>
  <div class="column youtube">Select the column that has the <span>Youtube</span> details</div>
  <div class="column gplus">Select the column that has the <span>GPlus</span> details</div>
  <div class="column instagram">Select the column that has the <span>Instagram</span> details</div>
  <div class="column confirm">Please Check the all column</div>
</div>
```

First of all , `step` are hidden by default with CSS and I did show first `step` with js code. You can find the JS code below:

```
$('.column.facebook').fadeIn('fast');
```

Say `step` showing `Select the column that has the Facebook details` so I should click any of table `header(th)` column and then this `header(th)` text will be replaced with the current `step` span tag content(Facebook) and add `active` class on current clicked table `header(th)` column and add `matched` class on current `step`. Like this

```
<div class="column facebook matched">Select the column that has the <span>Facebook</span> details</div>
```

If I click again on same table `header(th)` column then it will remove `active` class from current clicked table `header(th)` also remove `matched` class from current `step`.

When the first `step` is complete. Then I'll click next button to match another column. For now, it's ok and but there is one problem, when I click any of table `header(th)` column to match , at the same time I can select another table `header(th)` column for current `step` which is not my logic. But I want to select only one `header(th)` column for one `step`. Like Radio button option, if i click another radio option then previous selected option will be remove and current one will be selected.

I have some error on js , please have a look and tell how to achieve my business logic.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
td,th {border: 1px solid #000; cursor: pointer; }
.column { display: none; }
.active { background: red; }
span { color: red; font-weight: bold;}
button { padding: 10px 18px; background: red; cursor: pointer;}
.matched { background: green; }
</style>

<div class="table_required">
<div class="column facebook">Select the column that has the <span>Facebook</span> details</div>
<div class="column twitter">Select the column that has the <span>Twitter</span> details</div>
<div class="column youtube">Select the column that has the <span>Youtube</span> details</div>
<div class="column gplus">Select the column that has the <span>GPlus</span> details</div>
<div class="column instagram">Select the column that has the <span>Instagram</span> details</div>
<div class="column confirm">Please Check the all column</div>
</div>
<br>

<table id="table">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Column 0</th>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    <th>Column 3</th>
    <th>Column 4</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Facebook 0</td>
    <td>Twitter 0</td>
    <td>Youtube 0</td>
    <td>GPlus 0</td>
    <td>Instagram 0</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Facebook 1</td>
    <td>Twitter 1</td>
    <td>Youtube 1</td>
    <td>GPlus 1</td>
    <td>Instagram 1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Facebook 2</td>
    <td>Twitter 2</td>
    <td>Youtube 2</td>
    <td>GPlus 2</td>
    <td>Instagram 2</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<br>
<div class="button">
  <button class="next">Next</button>
</div>

<script>
$('.column.facebook').fadeIn('fast');
$('#table').on('click', 'th', function (e) {
    var col_indx = parseInt($(e.currentTarget).index()) + 1;

    $('.table_required .column').each(function () {
    var next_cls = $(this).next().find('span').text().toLowerCase();
    
        if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
            $(e.currentTarget).addClass('active').text($(this).find('span').text());

            var column = $(e.currentTarget).text();
            var rgxp = new RegExp(column, 'gi');

            if ($(this).find('span').text().match(rgxp)) {

                if (!$(this).hasClass('matched')) {
                    $(this).addClass('matched');
                    
                    if (next_cls) {
                        $(".next").attr('class', 'next ' + next_cls);
                    } else {
                        $(".next").attr('class', 'next confirm');
                    }
                } else {
                    $(this).removeClass('matched');

                    $(".next").attr('class', 'next');

                    $(e.currentTarget).removeClass('active').text('Column ' + parseInt(col_indx - 1));
                }
            }
        }
    });
});

next_click('twitter');
next_click('youtube');
next_click('gplus');
next_click('instagram');
next_click('confirm');

function next_click(selector) {
  $('.button').on('click', '.next.' + selector, function (e) {
      $('.table_required .column').each(function () {
          $(this).hide('fast');
      });
      
      if(selector == 'confirm') {
        $(this).html('Submit');
      }
      
      $(".table_required .column." + selector).fadeIn('fast').removeClass('matched');
  });
}
</script>
```

> Updated Code:

```
    $('.column.facebook').fadeIn('fast');
    $('#table').on('click', 'th', function (e) {
        var col_indx = parseInt($(e.currentTarget).index()) + 1;

        $('.table_required .column').each(function () {
            var next_cls = $(this).next().find('span').text().toLowerCase();

            if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
                if (!$(this).hasClass('matched') && !$(e.currentTarget).hasClass('active')) {
                    $(this).addClass('matched');

                    $(e.currentTarget).addClass('active').text($(this).find('span').text());

                    var column = $(e.currentTarget).text();
                    var rgxp = new RegExp(column, 'gi');

                    if ($(this).find('span').text().match(rgxp)) {
                        if (next_cls) {
                            $(".next").attr('class', 'next ' + next_cls);
                        } else {
                            $(".next").attr('class', 'next confirm' );
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $(this).removeClass('matched');

                    $('th:nth-child(' + col_indx + ')', $(e.currentTarget).closest('table')).removeClass('active').text('Column ' + parseInt(col_indx - 1));

                    if (next_cls) {
                        $(".next").attr('class', 'next' );
                    } else {
                        $(".next").attr('class', 'next' );
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });

    next_click('twitter');
    next_click('youtube');
    next_click('gplus');
    next_click('instagram');
    next_click('confirm');

    function next_click(selector) {
      $('.button').on('click', '.next.' + selector, function (e) {
          $('.table_required .column').each(function () {
              $(this).hide('fast');
          });

          if(selector == 'confirm') {
            $(this).html('Submit');
          }

          $(".table_required .column." + selector).fadeIn('fast').removeClass('matched');
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will meet your requirement

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
td,th {border: 1px solid #000; cursor: pointer; }
.column { display: none; }
.active { background: red; }
span { color: red; font-weight: bold;}
button { padding: 10px 18px; background: red; cursor: pointer;}
.matched { background: green; }
</style>

<div class="table_required">
<div class="column facebook">Select the column that has the <span>Facebook</span> details</div>
<div class="column twitter">Select the column that has the <span>Twitter</span> details</div>
<div class="column youtube">Select the column that has the <span>Youtube</span> details</div>
<div class="column gplus">Select the column that has the <span>GPlus</span> details</div>
<div class="column instagram">Select the column that has the <span>Instagram</span> details</div>
<div class="column confirm">Please Check the all column</div>
</div>
<br>

<table id="table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Column 0</th>
<th>Column 1</th>
<th>Column 2</th>
<th>Column 3</th>
<th>Column 4</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Facebook 0</td>
<td>Twitter 0</td>
<td>Youtube 0</td>
<td>GPlus 0</td>
<td>Instagram 0</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Facebook 1</td>
<td>Twitter 1</td>
<td>Youtube 1</td>
<td>GPlus 1</td>
<td>Instagram 1</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Facebook 2</td>
<td>Twitter 2</td>
<td>Youtube 2</td>
<td>GPlus 2</td>
<td>Instagram 2</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<br>
<div class="button">
<button class="next">Next</button>
</div>

<script>
$('.column.facebook').fadeIn();
$(".next").prop("disabled",true);
var that = null;
$("#table th").click(function(){
 if($(this).hasClass('active'))
  return false;
 $(".next").prop("disabled",false);
 var stepSpan = $(".column:visible > span").text();
 if(that)
  that.removeClass('active').text("Column "+ that.index())
 that = $(this);
 that.addClass('active').text(stepSpan);
 $(".column:visible").addClass("matched");
});
$(".next").click(function(){
 if($("#table th.active").length <5){
  $(".column:visible").removeClass("matched").hide().next().fadeIn();
  $(".next").prop("disabled",true);
  that = null;
 }
 else{
  console.log("Submit")// add final click logic here
 }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your coding standard as well business logic. Reused your code and met your requirement. compare your code with this code.

For this kind of scenario only to select any one at a time, need to keep the track of previously selected item so that we can remove the previous selection when we switch to new one.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
td,th {border: 1px solid #000; cursor: pointer; }
.column { display: none; }
.active { background: red; }
span { color: red; font-weight: bold;}
button { padding: 10px 18px; background: red; cursor: pointer;}
.matched { background: green; }
</style>

<div class="table_required">
<div class="column facebook">Select the column that has the <span>Facebook</span> details</div>
<div class="column twitter">Select the column that has the <span>Twitter</span> details</div>
<div class="column youtube">Select the column that has the <span>Youtube</span> details</div>
<div class="column gplus">Select the column that has the <span>GPlus</span> details</div>
<div class="column instagram">Select the column that has the <span>Instagram</span> details</div>
<div class="column confirm">Please Check the all column</div>
</div>
<br>

<table id="table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Column 0</th>
<th>Column 1</th>
<th>Column 2</th>
<th>Column 3</th>
<th>Column 4</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Facebook 0</td>
<td>Twitter 0</td>
<td>Youtube 0</td>
<td>GPlus 0</td>
<td>Instagram 0</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Facebook 1</td>
<td>Twitter 1</td>
<td>Youtube 1</td>
<td>GPlus 1</td>
<td>Instagram 1</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Facebook 2</td>
<td>Twitter 2</td>
<td>Youtube 2</td>
<td>GPlus 2</td>
<td>Instagram 2</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<br>
<div class="button">
<button class="next">Next</button>
</div>

<script>
$('.column.facebook').fadeIn('fast');
var col_indxCopy;
$('#table').on('click', 'th', function (e) {

    if(!!col_indxCopy){
        console.log($( "#table th:eq( "+ parseInt(col_indxCopy-1)+" )" ))

       $( "#table th:eq( "+ parseInt(col_indxCopy-1)+" )" ).removeClass('active').text('Column ' + parseInt(col_indxCopy-1));
    }

    var col_indx = parseInt($(e.currentTarget).index()+1);
    $('.table_required .column').each(function () {
    var next_cls = $(this).next().find('span').text().toLowerCase();
    
        if ($(this).is(":visible")) {

            if(!$(e.currentTarget).hasClass('active') && !$(this).hasClass('matched'))
            $(e.currentTarget).addClass('active').text($(this).find('span').text());
            else
            $(e.currentTarget).removeClass('active').text('Column ' + parseInt(col_indx-1));
           
            var column = $(e.currentTarget).text();
            var rgxp = new RegExp(column, 'gi');

            if ($(this).find('span').text().match(rgxp)) {

                if (!$(this).hasClass('matched')) {
                    $(this).addClass('matched');
                    
                    if (next_cls) {
                        $(".next").attr('class', 'next ' + next_cls);
                    } else {
                        $(".next").attr('class', 'next confirm');
                    }
                } else {
                    if(col_indxCopy == col_indx){
                     $(this).removeClass('matched');

                    $(".next").attr('class', 'next');
                    }
                   

                  
                }
            }
            // if($(e.currentTarget).hasClass('active'))
            //   
        }
    });
    col_indxCopy = col_indx;
});

next_click('twitter');
next_click('youtube');
next_click('gplus');
next_click('instagram');
next_click('confirm');

function next_click(selector) {
  $('.button').on('click', '.next.' + selector, function (e) {
      $('.table_required .column').each(function () {
          $(this).hide('fast');
      });
      
      if(selector == 'confirm') {
        $(this).html('Submit');
      }
      
      $(".table_required .column." + selector).fadeIn('fast').removeClass('matched');
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please take a look my question again, i have update it.

Comment: do you want to remove the previous selected column when select another column on same step? Like radio button option

Comment: Do you want to remove the selection once move to next?

Comment: No, When move next, previous one should still selected